# How to implement chat functionality in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, chat

I want to implement a simple online chat application in WP7.
I am using Matrix SDK to implement chat on my WP7
This is how I am trying to connect but I am not able to connect and send any messages.
Neither the events are getting fired..I am not getting any exception also..
what have I done wrong????
Please guide me

Thanks in advance

```
XmppClient xmppConn;
xmppConn = new XmppClient();            
Jid jidUser = new Jid("username");
xmppConn.Username = jidUser.User;
xmppConn.Password = "password";
    xmppConn.SetXmppDomain(jidUser.Server);           
xmppConn.Uri = new System.Uri("http://server.com:7070/http-bind/",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
xmppConn.Status = "Testing on Windows Phone 7";
xmppConn.Show = Matrix.Xmpp.Show.Chat;
try
        {
            xmppConn.Open();
            xmppConn.OnLogin += new EventHandler<Matrix.EventArgs>(xmppConn_OnLogin);
            //xmppConn.OnPresence += new EventHandler<PresenceEventArgs>(xmppConn_OnPresence);
            // xmpp.OnLogin += new EventHandler<Matrix.EventArgs>(xmpp_OnLogin);                
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong login data!");
        }     
    }

private void SendButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // loose focus to hide keyboard
        this.Focus();
        messages.Add(new ChatMessage()
        {
            Side = MessageSide.Me,
            Text = TextInput.Text
        });

        var pm = new PresenceManager(xmppConn);
        string sub_id = "xxxxxxxxx";
        Jid jid = sub_id;
        pm.Subscribe(jid);
        xmppConn.Send(new  Message(new Jid(jid), MessageType.chat, TextInput.Text));
        xmppConn.OnMessage += new EventHandler<MessageEventArgs>(xmppConn_OnMessage);
        TextInput.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: hey any idea y this code not workin?????

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) for real time web based communications (including chat).

There is an [official sample for Windows Phone 8](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/samples/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.WP8.Sample) and also a [3rd party helper for WP7](http://wp7signalrhelper.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Hi Matt..I have placed some code that i am working on...Pls have a look n get back to me if I have done it correctly r not

Comment: I downloaded the code here:http://www.ag-software.de/matrix-xmpp-sdk/download/ (for windows phone)and I just gave my credentials...the Onerror event is getting fired....I dont know wats wrong with the code

Answer (score 0):

Before doing anything on xmpp you first need to set OnBind Event of xmmp class.

**Reason**: Most of the xmpp works asynchronously.When you call something like client.Open it returns immediately so you first need to wait for OnBind event.